# Reverse Negative Integers and 0

Tags: python, list, for-loop, reverse, python-3.6

An exercise from LeetCode ask to reverse integer and this is the code I got, but it doesn't work for negative integers and integers that starts with 0. How can I include that?

```
class Solution:
    def reverse(self, x):
        self.x = x
        y = str(x)
        list_mod = list(y)

        for i in list_mod:
            list_mod.reverse()
            join_list = ''.join(list_mod[:])

        print(join_list)
```

Comment: What do you mean by reversing a number? Can you show example please?

Comment: Why is this in a class? Why do you assign to `self.x`? Please remove extraneous stuff from your question, don't just dump your code here. Simply stating "it doesn't work" isn't an adequate explanation. Please provide a [mcve]. There are certain guidelines for asking questions. Please see [ask]

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga LeetCode intentionally makes you put your solution in a class. It's how they format it

Comment: @JafferWilson The problem states given a number (eg: `123`), reverse it (i.e: `321`)

Comment: @TerryA yes, I understand that this comes from a submission, my point is, one shouldn't just *dump code* and ask unspecified questions. I'm trying to get the OP to improve their question to gain some traction, but providing an [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) question. Specifically, *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.*

Comment: @TerryA Thanks.. As this was a need for the question. I was a bit confused with what he meant.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
int(str(123)[::-1])
```

Just replace the number with the suitable integer variable in your program and you will certainly get the reverse of the number you want.

After Getting your complete requirement this is what I can suggest from my end:

```
x = -123
y = str(x)
if y[0] == '-':
    list_mod = list(y)
    list_mod.pop(0)
    list_mod.append('-')
    list_mod.reverse()
    join_list = ''.join(list_mod[:])

print(join_list)
```

Comment: wow impressive... I wrote a whole class that does the same thing and all you did was one line. What does [::-1] mean? But I am working on the exercise on LeetCode. I'm not sure if that one line will be the right answer... I think LeetCode is asking for a definition. Nonetheless, Wow.

Comment: @aiduaq Why can't you try it once.. If it doesn't helps you that you can let me know so that I will find out something else... :) Thank you for your appreciation

Comment: Sorry for the wording of my comment. I meant to say I did try it both on LeetCode as well as Python Shell. It worked just fine in Python Shell but LeetCode doesn't seem to accept the code. Is there a way to code it into a method with x being the variable of the int? Also sorry in advance if my question seems hard to understand. Completely new to the field of CS.

Comment: @aiduaq Why you have written `for i in list_mod:`? It is absolutely not required. You can directly reverse a list.. let me edit the answer of mine.

Comment: And tell me what if you have number starting with zero and minus? What output do you expect for such numbers.... Please write a bit about it.

Comment: Check the answer now.. this will surely help you.